# Is it possible to compare strings from the same variable in C?

Tags: c, string, string-comparison

I wanted to try to compare characters of strings from the same variable so I could just use *for* when comparing several other strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {

    char this_string[2][10] = {"Jason", "jason"},
    string1[6] = "Jason",
    string2[6] = "jason",
    ans[6];

    int x;

    for (x=0; x<5; x++) {
        if (string1[x]!=string2[x]) {
            strcpy(ans, string2);
            ans[x] = '-';
        }   
    }

    printf("%s\n", ans);

}
```

The output would be "-ason". But is there a way to do the same with this_string?

Comment: is their strcmp is available na?

Comment: i was hoping to compare characters between string1 and string2?

Comment: @Jongware check once again it is  `string1[x] != string2[x];`

Comment: @Sample here Shane is comparing character not string

Comment: @Jongware what is your way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes do like this :

```
 for (x=0; x<5; x++) {
        if (this_string[0][x]!=this_string[1][x]) {
            strcpy(ans, this_string[1]);
            ans[x] = '-';
        }   
    }
```